# how to pass e.target.textContent in td contentEditable={true} to other component?

Tags: reactjs, html-table, components

I am very very new to react. I am working with a table doing a basic CRUD using MERN.

Everything is fine but I want to make a put request for editing the table's values.

so far, what I am trying to do is to edit the content on the table itself, this way:

```
<td onInput={(e) => e.target.textContent} contentEditable={true} suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>{informacion.responsable}</td>
<td onInput={(e) => e.target.textContent} contentEditable={true} suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>{informacion.noSello}</td>
<td onInput={(e) => e.target.textContent} contentEditable={true} suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>{informacion.identificadorEquipo}</td>
```

and in deed now with a console.log I can see the (e.target.textContent)

then...in the same component in which this table structre appears I have another component(the edit button component). What this button does is to perform a put request but I need the e.target.textContent values from my `<td>` in order to inserting them as a json

```
<EditButton value1={td1} value2={td2} value3={td3}/>
```

1-How can this be done?

2-Is this approach bad at all?

thanks to all for you time

Answer (score 0):

Since you're *very very* new at this, it's time you start learning about `state`. First you'll have to import the state hook: 
`import { useState } from React;`
So basically what you can do in this case is declare a state variable as: 
`const[content , setContent] = useState('');` 
Now, you'll have a state of `content` that stores that `e.target.textContent` and you can set the state by the `setContent` setter. 
Now, you can write your `td` component as: 
`<td onInput={(e) => setContent(e.target.textContent)} contentEditable={true} suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>{informacion.responsable}</td>` 
This shall set your `content` state with the `e.target.textContent`. Now, if you want to pass this to the `EditButton` component, you can do it as: 
`<EditButton value1={content}/>`

Comment: I will try .thanks.I often forget that all is about state here

Comment: and what would happend if I have 60 `td`...should I use useState, or useReducer, or something else?

Comment: @MaykelContrerasCamacho Well, that's up to you and your programming logic. But if you have to use 60 states for this, you might wanna step back and really think about how to better structure your application.

Comment: the table I am about to use has 60 fields..can not run from that fact